# Como tratar o evento gerado pelo botão back do Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8-1

## Nas versões anteriores era possivel fazer tal manipulação sobreescrevendo o OnBackKeyPress.

```
 protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {            
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

Porém é apresentado dois erros:

> .OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)' é um novo
>      membro virtual na classe selada
>
> .OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)' nenhum
>      método adequado    encontrado para substituir

**Como fazer o mesmo na nova versão do Windows Phone ?**

Answer (score 1):

Você está criando um projeto universal?

Tente:

```
public static event EventHandler<BackPressedEventArgs> BackPressed
```

Answer (score 1):

tente configurar a propriedade BackPressedEventArgs.Handled para true.

```
private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        if (frame == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (frame.CanGoBack)
        {
            frame.GoBack();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```